# Lightning Action to VisualForce Page. Why opens in new Window?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

I have lightning action set to open VF page. But not sure why it is opening into new browser window. Is there any hidden configuration? i do not see any navigation rule on Lightning action edit page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lightning action opening a VF page should work normal , their is no any specific settings required. If in your case its trying to open in different tab then it might be related to your browser settings or the VF page containing code functionality.

Comment: Same issue occurs if i put some dummy VF page that simply displays static text.